# Oracle Query to rollup QTY by Year

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a requirement to find out MAX VALUE from SUM of Quantities Divided by YEAR (Need to write a Oracle Query).

For Example

```
 ITEM_ID     ORG_ID     YEAR    QTY

  100         121        2015    10
  100         121        2016    5
  100         121        2017    8
  101         146        2014    10
  101         146        2015    11
  101         146        2016    12
  101         146        2017    13
```

My Output should be like this :-

`for Item_id 100,121   the max_avg should be max(10+5+8/3, 5+10/2, 10/1)... max (7.6, 7.5, 8) = 8`
      `for Item_id 101,146   the max_avg should be max(10+11+12+13/4, 11+12+13/3, 12+13/2, 13/1)... max(11.5, 12, 12.5, 13) = 13`

```
 ITEM_ID     ORG_ID     YEAR    QTY   MAX_AVG

  100         121        2015    10   8
  100         121        2016    5    8
  100         121        2017    8    8
  101         146        2014    10   13
  101         146        2015    11   13
  101         146        2016    12   13
  101         146        2017    13   13
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand the logic behind your various max calculations.  Can you explain that?

Comment: Please clarify what your logic is

Comment: Hi Tim, Since ITEM_ID, Org_ID (100,121) has QTY for three years 2015,2016,2017.. I need the find out the AVG for 2015,2016,2017 Qty, Similarly AVG for 2016,2017 Qty and AVG for 2017... I need to get the MAX of these three averages... if I have 4 years for ITEm_ID, ORG_ID combination, I need to find the MAX from the Four Averages. Please kindly let me know if you need any more information. Thanks alot

Comment: @ Jacob - Please find my explanation above and let me know of any more questions..

Comment: Your explanation doesn't match the numbers you show. If you need the averages for 2015-2016-2017, 2016-2017 and 2017, they are (10+8+5)/3, (5+8)/2 and 8/1. The MAX is 8.

Comment: @mathguy - Thanks for correcting me . I have corrected my numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need two layers of analytic functions: You need analytic MAX (of *something*) because you want to return all rows from the original table; and within the MAX you need analytic (rolling) average. Analytic functions can't be nested, so you need a subquery and an outer query. Something like this:

```
with inputs ( item_id, org_id, yr, qty ) as (
            select 100, 121, 2015, 10 from dual
  union all select 100, 121, 2016,  5 from dual
  union all select 100, 121, 2017,  8 from dual
  union all select 101, 146, 2014, 10 from dual
  union all select 101, 146, 2015, 11 from dual
  union all select 101, 146, 2016, 12 from dual
  union all select 101, 146, 2017, 13 from dual
)
-- End of simulated inputs (for testing only, not part of the solution).
-- SQL query begins BELOW THIS LINE. Use your actual table and column names.
select item_id, org_id, yr, qty, 
       max(forward_avg) over ( partition by item_id, org_id  ) as max_avg
from   ( select item_id, org_id, yr, qty, 
                avg(qty) over ( partition by item_id, org_id 
                                order by yr desc             ) as forward_avg
         from   inputs i
       ) b
order by item_id, org_id, yr   --   If needed
;

   ITEM_ID     ORG_ID         YR        QTY    MAX_AVG
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
       100        121       2015         10          8
       100        121       2016          5          8
       100        121       2017          8          8
       101        146       2014         10         13
       101        146       2015         11         13
       101        146       2016         12         13
       101        146       2017         13         13
```

Comment: Good, i have the same query, i has been success. 1 vote

Comment: @Mathguy - How can I restrict this Query to look for the Avg only for last 3 years and assign the value?. I mean the mas should be calculated only for max (current_year/1, current_year+previous_year/2, current_year+previous_year+previous_Previous_year/3). That's it. I shouldn't consider /4, /5... scenarios.

Comment: That is quite different, since in "this" query you are assigning the same MAX_AVG to all years (so, for example, to ID 100, year 2015, you assign a MAX_AVG that includes FUTURE years). The problems are "similar" but actually quite different; you may be better off posting it as a new question. Also, if/when you do, state your Oracle version (such as 11.2.0.4.0) since different solutions are possible in different versions.

Comment: @mathguy - I have created the new question... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46833821/oracle-query-to-rollup-qty-by-year-only-last-3-years