# Oracle Query to rollup QTY by Year- only last 3 years

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I have a requirement to find out MAX VALUE from SUM of Quantities Divided by YEAR (Need to write a Oracle Query).

For Example

```
 ITEM_ID     ORG_ID     YEAR    QTY

  100         121        2015    10
  100         121        2016    5
  100         121        2017    8
  101         146        2014    10
  101         146        2015    11
  101         146        2016    12
  101         146        2017    13
```

My Output should be like this :-

`for Item_id 100,121   the max_avg should be max(10+5+8/3, 5+10/2, 10/1)... max (7.6, 7.5, 8) = 8`
      `for Item_id 101,146   the max_avg should be  (11+12+13/3, 12+13/2, 13/1)... max(11.5, 12, 12.5, 13) = 13... I should not consider 10+11+12+13/4`. I only need the consider the AVG rolled up by last 3 years and assign the Max Value

```
 ITEM_ID     ORG_ID     YEAR    QTY   MAX_AVG

  100         121        2015    10   8
  100         121        2016    5    8
  100         121        2017    8    8
  101         146        2014    10   13
  101         146        2015    11   13
  101         146        2016    12   13
  101         146        2017    13   13
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is that the desired output? How does ID 101, year 2016, get assigned the value 13 in the new column? If that is not the desired output, please edit to show the (correct) desired output. In particular, for ID 101 (for example), what should be shown for 2014 and 2015, when there aren't three years to consider? Perhaps for 2014 just show the QTY (10), and for 2015 show the max of 11/1 and (10+11)/2? If not, what else?

Comment: Also: what is your Oracle version, as reported by `select * from v$version`?

Comment: @mathguy - the version is Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

Comment: @mathguy - Yes that's the desired Output. Always there would be three years to consider starting from the current year and 2 previous years.

Comment: Oh... so, you compute the max over (year 2017), (avg of 2016, 2017), (avg over 2015, 2016, 2017) and you assign it to ALL the years for given ITEM_ID and ORG_ID?

Comment: In that case, still, what do you do if ITEM_ID = 102, ORG_ID = 200 (not currently shown in your sample data), you have QTY only for 2017, or only for 2016 and 2017? Also: Is it possible that for a combination of ITEM_ID and ORG_ID you have data only for 2014, 2015 and 2016 but not 2017? If so, what data to use in the computation?

Comment: @mathguy - that's the maximum right of (11+12+13/3, 12+13/2, 13/1)... max(11.5, 12, 12.5, 13) = 13. that value should be assigned to current year (2017), previous year (2016) and previous to previous year (2015)..

Comment: @ mathguy - In that case, still, what do you do if ITEM_ID = 102, ORG_ID = 200 (not currently shown in your sample data), you have QTY only for 2017, or only for 2016 and 2017? Also: Is it possible that for a combination of ITEM_ID and ORG_ID you have data only for 2014, 2015 and 2016 but not 2017? If so, what data to use in the computation?  -- For this question I always will have 3 years worth of data in the source starting from current_year, -1 and -2 of current_year. if there is no qty also we have defaulted them to Zeros in the source.

Comment: Oh... so, you compute the max over (year 2017), (avg of 2016, 2017), (avg over 2015, 2016, 2017) and you assign it to ALL the years for given ITEM_ID and ORG_ID? -- ExActly what I want. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select item_id, org_id, yr, qty,
       greatest (
 avg(case when yr = 2017                then qty end) over (partition by item_id, org_id),
 avg(case when yr in (2016, 2017)       then qty end) over (partition by item_id, org_id),
 avg(case when yr in (2015, 2016, 2017) then qty end) over (partition by item_id, org_id)
       ) as max_avg
from   inputs_table
;
```

Comment: this worked. I have changed the query to be more dynamic. :)

        `select item_id, org_id, yr, qty,
       greatest (
 avg(case when yr = (select to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY') from dual)                 then qty end) over (partition by item_id, org_id),
 avg(case when yr >= (select to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY')-1 from dual)       then qty end) over (partition by item_id, org_id),
 avg(case when yr >= (select to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY')-2 from dual) then qty end) over (partition by item_id, org_id)
       ) as max_avg
from   inputs_table
;`

Answer (score 2):

One method uses two levels of analytic functions:

```
select t.*, max(running_avg_3) over (partition by item_id)
from (select t.*,
             avg(qty) over (partition by item_id order by year desc
                            rows between current row and 2 following
                           ) as running_avg_3
      from t
     ) t
```

Comment: This is not what the OP is looking for. In a "partition" he looks only at the averages over 2017, 2017 and 2016, and 2017, 2016 and 2015. This "greatest of three averages) is used for ALL years, including for 2011 and 2012 and 2013. It is not explained very clearly in the original post, but it is clarified in the Comments.

Comment: @ Gordon - I thought this query will work. But it still didn't work and its calculating for 2014 also.

Comment: @beckham . . . The windowing clause needs to go in the other direction -- 2 following rather than 2 preceding.